# Rails 5 ActiveRecord w/ PostgreSQL where with dynamic field name and custom operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I have Rails 5 w/ PostgresSQL 11, this dynamic, custom, query.  `target_field` is dynamic from a complex controller/action, though no user-input;  it's value here is for example.

```
target_field = 'title'
query = 'Test'
Model.where("#{target_field} ~* ?", query)
```

How can I avoid the Deprecation warning:  "Dangerous query method .. on ["title"] " ?

I've tried variations on wrapping `target_field` or parts of the query in `Arel.sql()` with no success.

Thanks!
Peter Fitzgibbons